# Solve in $\mathbb{R}$ the equation : $x^4+x-4=0$

Tags: functions, roots

How do I solve, in $\mathbb{R}$, the following  equation : $x^4+x-4=0$. I used the function $f(x)=x^4+x-4$ to prove that it has exactly two solutions;  one less than, and the other great than $-\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{1}{4}}$. But I don't know how to find the solutions.

Comment: You must derivate and see when it is crescent or not and then use Intermediate value theorem

Comment: This is exactely what I used, I have mentioned it in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Since this isn't factorable, you could graph it and then find the zeroes / x-intercepts. Using desmos, I got x = -1.534 and x = 1.284.

Comment: Why this isn't factorable ?

Answer (score 0):

If we use the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) we have six possible candidates $\pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 4.$ Unfortunately none of these provides an actual zero. Thus this is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}.$

Now lets try to solve it over $\mathbb{R}.$ If it is reducible over reals, by [Descartes rule of signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs) we have exactly one positive real zero and a negative real zero. Therefore it is enough to show it has some roots over reals. Let $$f(x)=x^4+x-4.$$ Note that $f(2)=14,$ $f(0)=-4$ and $f(-2)=10.$ Thus by the [intermediate value theorem,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) it has some (irrational) real roots in the intervals $(-2,0)$ and $(0,2).$

> Hence this equation has exactly two real roots and a pair of complex conjugate roots.

Comment: If you want to find the location of roots relative to $-4^{-1/3},$ (the only real root of $f'(x)=0$)  evaluate $f$ at this point and use the intermediate value theorem.